# Is there a script/app that allows me to switch between versions of Cocoapods?

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

I'd like to run alpha/beta versions and current releases alongside older versions.

For instance, I'd like to easily switch between Cocoapods 0.33.1 and 0.34-RC2.

Especially for older apps that we can't invest much time into, that Cocoapods either no longer supports some Podfile formatting, or the Podspec we are referencing uses deprecated directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rvm to set up multiple ruby environments. http://rvm.io

Comment: Just to add to this. You specifically want to use different [gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets).